# Alternating Tables

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have three tables and each table has its own dataset:

Table A - Dataset A
Table B - Dataset B
Table C - Dataset C

When running the report I get this:

Table A
Table A
Table A
...

Table B
Table B
Table B
...

Table C
Table C
Table C
...

First all the Data of table A is displayed, then table B, then table C. What I want to achieve is that the tables are alternating. It should look like this:

Table A
Table B
Table C
Table A
Table B
Table C
...

Unfortunatly it is not possible to join these three tables via SQL and I want to avoid to use the lookupset-expression, because then all the data would be displayed in one single cell and not in rows and that looks badly. Or is there a way to generate an new row via expression, similar to Environment.NewLine?

Comment: *"because then all the data would be displayed in one single cell"* Why would it? A small sample of data and expected results would help as it's unclear what you want. It sounds like you want a single row from table A, then a single row from B and then C, and then repeat but I guess there is some relationship between the tables and the order of rows, it's just not obvious at the moment. Add some more detail and you will get better help.

Comment: You *could* add extra rows to the Row Group and use the LookUpset to the other datasets in each row but that would be slow and issues if the other datasets have more data than the initial dataset.

Comment: In this example I only use two tables A and B. Table A contains all the planets of the solar system, i.e. Mercury, Venus, Earth etc. Table B contains all the moons, i.e. Moon, Phobos, Deimos etc.
In report I want to present the planets and their moons. In this greatly simplified example, it appears that the two tables could join via SQL, but in reality it is much more complicated and therefore unfortunately not possible.
I want to represent each planet and its moons in a tablix. Since these are two datasets, the moons have to be added via lookupset, but then all the moons are in one cell.

Comment: I think the best would be to use subreports for the other 2 tables. I assume there some sort of way to associate the planets to the moons that would be used for the parameters. Then add extra add extra Row in Group for the Moon subreport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think the best would be to use subreports for the other 2 tables. I assume there some sort of way to associate the planets to the moons that would be used for the parameters. Then add extra add extra Row in Group for the Moon subreport.

The solution proposed by Hannover First works fine. Working with Sub-Reports solves my problem.

Thanks.

Comment: If a comment proposed by another user worked for you, consider quoting his original comment in your answer. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).